# How to find custom WorkflowInstanceID in Designer workflow?

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a list with 3 workflows: A, B, C.
I want to show their status in a single new field S.

So, S should contain, for example this information:
"
Status of A: In Progress
Status of B: In Progress
Status of C: Completed
"

Here, the problem is how to create the link to the workflows A, B, C? They all show the link in SharePoint list views as_layouts/WrkStat.aspx?WorkflowInstanceID=GUID

How to get the WorkflowInstanceID guid, to create the link?

want to group workflow titles and links to one column. I can read the workflow status id values from other custom workflow columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use default SharePoint Designer variable (available from "Add or Change Lookup", Data source - "Workflow Context", Field from source - "Workflow Status URL", return as string)

> [%Workflow Context:Workflow Status URL%]

which will return string like this:

```
http://servername/_layouts/WrkStat.aspx?List=d34a779d-e699-4e36-87e8-8840409197f7&WorkflowInstanceID=d49af800-a5a8-475b-871c-9ed2dab9bdf4
```

where you can trim guid using SharePoint Designer Action "Extract Substring from End of String".

```
d49af800-a5a8-475b-871c-9ed2dab9bdf4
```

But i suppose you can create a custom column (e.g. Choice type) which will describe workflow status in current moment of time so you can always change the workflow status using SharePoint Designer action "Set Field in Current Item" and refer to this status from any step in your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

In fact `Workflow Context` contains field for storing `Workflow Instance Id`, see picture below for details

[image]

For more details about `Workflow Context` members follow [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.workflowcontext_members.aspx)

---

The construction of a value for a field in the following format:

```
Status of {WorkflowInstanceId} <a href="/_layouts/WrkStat.aspx?WorkflowInstanceID={WorkflowInstanceId}>{WorkflowName}</a>
```

in SPD Builder looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the above doesn't work for me. I am using workflow 2013. The below works for me.

```
/_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List=[%Workflow Context:List ID%]&WorkflowInstanceName=[%Workflow Context:Instance ID%]
```